# Cantonese Question: When does one use 咩 versus 乜野?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference, cantonese

I've been listening to some Cantonese audio from Pimsleur and noticed they use a different word for "what" compared to what I learned from CantoneseClass101. In CC101, they used 咩, such as "咩事啊?", whereas the audio I just listened to is using sentences like "你想飲乜野啊?" What is the difference if any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)). (合音)

> [Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese) contracts 乜嘢 (mat1 ye5)[4] 'what?' to 咩 (me1).

Common words spoken fast often have the first initial mixed in with the last final. For example 咩 takes the "m" from 乜 and the ending "e" from 嘢, creating the contracted form: *me*.

Same meaning, same usage - just quicker speeds.

You will find many contractions in Chinese topolects.

Comment: Is that then analogous to 什麽 and 啥 in Mandarin? Cuz that would make a lot of sense if that was the case.

Comment: The linked page doesn't have examples of Cantonese contraction. E.g. 係唔係 -->係咪

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand It has been proposed that 啥 is [probably a fusion of 什麼／什么 (shénme)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%95%A5#Chinese), so yes that is correct.

Comment: This brings me to suggest that the verbal contraction of 乜野 to 咩 with the latter written with a "Sheep",  羊, component, is no coincidence as the 咩 sounds like the bleating sheep. Listen to this:- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sheep_bleating.ogg

Comment: The contraction of 乜嘢 sounds kind of like me1 e5 (kind of like a descending tone which doesn't otherwise exist in Cantonese), whereas the particle 咩 is pronounced me1. So to me, they are not the same.